# spark sql hive connection error

Tags: scala, maven, hadoop, hive

I am facing issue with Scala IDE in my Spark project.

I can not connect to `HiveContext`. The error it gives is

```
object hive is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
```

Code statement is

```
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

Following are the version being used in the project:

> Scala - 2.11.8
>
> Java - 1.8
>
> Spark - 2.1.0

pom.xml for reference is

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- mixed scala/java compile -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- for fatjar -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemble-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- <configuration> <archive> <manifest> <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> 
                <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass> </manifest> </archive> </configuration> -->
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                                    <artifactId> maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange> [2.15.2,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

`

Comment: Not a solution but `HiveContext` is deprecated. You can use `SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport`. Also, why not `spark-hive_2.11`?

Comment: @philantrovert thanks for your reply. Even, `SparkSession` is not available and throws the same error. 
I guess there is a dependency problem which I tried with spark_hive-2.11 also but no resolution.

Comment: How are you running this jar?

Comment: @philantrovert this seems to resolve after a few `mvn install` done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to resolve after a few `mvn install` done.
thanks.